# Intuition for why $\left|\sigma_{XY}\right|\leq \sigma_X \sigma_Y$ (|covariance| $\leq$ product of standard deviations)?

Tags: standard-deviation, covariance

The population correlation coefficient is defined as $$\rho=\frac{\sigma_{XY}}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}.$$

I was looking for an intuitive explanation for why $\rho\in[-1,1]$.

Or equivalently, why $$\left|\sigma_{XY}\right|\leq \sigma_X \sigma_Y.$$

The usual proof involves the Cauchy-Schwartz inequality. Another proof is that $\rho$ can be viewed as the cosine of the angle between two vectors and must thus be in $[-1,1]$.

But I was wondering if there was a more intuitive proof as to why the inequality above is true. It might go something like this:

> The LHS is $\sigma_{XY}$ --- this is "the degree to which $X$ and $Y$
>   covary". The RHS is the product of $\sigma_{X}$ and $\sigma_{Y}$ ---
>   these are "the degree to which $X$ varies" and "the degree to which
>   $Y$ varies". ... **Intuition I'm seeking** ... Therefore,
>   $\left|LHS\right|\leq RHS$.

Comment: I found this intuition on the CS inequality useful: https://jakubmarian.com/intuition-behind-the-cauchy-schwarz-markovs-and-jensens-inequality/ Heuristically translated to statistics, this statement can be read as saying that no other variable can predict the movements of a variable $X$ than $X$ itself.

Comment: "better than" $X$ itself, it should read

Comment: Do you find it intuitive that the mean of two random quantities (whether or not they are correlated) is no more variable than the random quantities themselves?